# Is there a simple way to use scp that will behave like rsync -u or cp -u

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp

I'd like to be able to upload to my remote server only updating new files.  I am using a nanoblogger, and it appears to upload the entire thing every time using plain scp -r, but I can't find any -u option for scp mentioned in the man pages.

I suppose I could try to somehow script the upload with an ls or find that grabs only files updated in the last $n minutes, or something, but that seems heavy handed.

Answer (score 5):

Use rsync over SSH.

I you can `scp`, you can very probably rsync over ssh:

```
rsync -a /some/dir/ user@server:/dest/dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

scp doesn't have any conditional option, and probably won't get it anytime soon. rsync seems like a very reasonable way, if it is installed on the target system; if not, some find + uniq magic could do the job, but would be serious work. Compiling rsync would probably be faster :-).

Comment: rsync is not on the target system.  It's a CentOS server, but I do not have root (shared hosting).  Does rsync have to be on both systems to work?

Comment: Yes, but userspace suffices. I've personally used rsync on SDF by compiling it from source as a user: ./configure --prefix=$HOME/bin && make && make install was sufficient IIRC.